# How to match the word between digits and colon with sed

Tags: sed

I am trying to figure out how to match everything between the time and the colon (the colon should also be removed) with sed. The time can be different (24H format) and should not be limited to 21:30 which is the example here.

I am trying to delete the UNWANTED TEXT:

```
#EXTINF:-1,21:30 UNWANTED TEXT: Apples - Oranges
```

The output wanted:

```
#EXTINF:-1,21:30 Apples - Oranges
```

Can anyone help me with this?

I tried following, this works however it is based on whitespace always being there and I want to use the time as the pattern.

```
sed 's# .*:##g'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: Edited my post. Want to add that I am completely new to this and regex.

Comment: will the *only* digits be the time or could digits show up elsewhere in the string? if digits can show up elsewhere then please update the question with more samples; also, where is this string coming from ... a variable? output from a command? a line in a file? and if one of the latter two then will all lines need to be edited or just some lines?

Comment: The digits will only be time. The string is coming from a M3U Playlist, and there are alot of lines like this. I put the whole m3u in a variable and trying to execute sed to do what I want before I output it to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No claims to elegance, but how about:
`sed 's/\(.*[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}\)[^:]*:\(.*\)/\1\2/'`

This requires the time to be two digits, colon, two digits, and will likely fail if that pattern occurs more than once in the string.

Breaking down the regular expression `\(.*[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}\)[^:]*:\(.*\)`:

```
\( - start a grouping
.*  - match any character until we find the next pattern, [0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}
[0-9] - match any digit
[0-9]\{2\} - match any two digits
[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\} - match ab:cd, where a,b,c,d are single decimal digits
\) - end the first grouping. We'll later refer to all the characters matched by this grouping as "\1"
[^:]* - match any character that's not a colon
[^:]*: - match any number of non-colon characters followed by a single colon. This is what we'll remove from the string.
\( - start the second grouping
\(.*\) - match any characters in the second grouping, which we'll refer to later as "\2"
```

Once we've done that match, we've more or less split our string into three pieces:

- The first grouping, called "\1", which is everything from the start of the string to the time
- The part of the string we're going to remove, which immediately follows the time and consists of a number of non-colon characters followed by a ":"
- The second grouping, which is everything after the colon.

Basically, we replace these three pieces with the first grouping and the second grouping. That's accomplished by the `/\1\2/` part of the sed command.

Sed regex reference: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/([0-9]+:[0-9]+)[^:]*:/\1/' input_file
#EXTINF:-1,21:30 Apples - Oranges
```

Answer (score 1):

If the line can potentially contain something that looks like the timestamp in more than one place, you may want to start the match at the beginning of the line:

```
sed -E 's/^(#[^:]+:-?[0-9]+,[0-9]+:[0-9]+)[^:]+:/\1/'
```

- `-E` - Extended regular expressions
- `^` - Start of the line anchor
- `(` - Start of capture group 1
- `#[^:]+` - A literal `#` followed by one or more non-colon characters
- `:-?` - A literal `:` followed by zero or one `-`
- `[0-9]+,` - One or more digits followed by a `,`
- `[0-9]+:` - One or more digits followed by a `:`
- `)` - End of capture group 1
- `[^:]+:` - One or more non-colons followed by a colon. Not captured. This is where  `UNWANTED TEXT` should be

The above match is then replaced by

- `\1` - Capture 1 (which doesn't include  `UNWANTED TEXT`)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

cat << EOF >> edpop
2d
wq
EOF

string=$(echo "#EXTINF:-1,21:30 UNWANTED TEXT: Apples - Oranges")

str1= $(echo "${string}" | sed 's@UNWANTED@%UNWANTED@')
str2= $(echo "${str1}" | sed 's@Apples@%Apples@')

echo "${str2}" | tr '%' '\n' > file
ed -s file < edpop
cat file | tr '\n' ':' | sed s'@30:Apples@30 Apples@' | sed s'@Oranges:@Oranges@ > file2
mv file2 file
```